# How to add a view from an external reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to load some views from an external dll. My problem is that I don't know how to do it. What I have for now is the dll added to my main aplication and
I already tried this:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
  options.FileProviders.Add(embeddedFileProviderHeader);
});
```

but I saw this is only used for AspNet Core, what is a problem, because I'm using AspNet Mvc 5. So, is there something similar to **RazorViewEngineOptions** for AspNet Mvc 5?